# Compare array key and get value in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have array which show result like this :

```
Array ( [standards_id] => 1 
    [value] => sory 
    [order] => 10
) 
Array ( [standards_id] => 1 
    [value] => javid 
    [order] => 3
) 
Array ( [standards_id] => 1 
    [value] => saleem 
    [order] => 4
).
```

I want to check the array key ,if it is "value" then i want to concatenate its value.I try code like this but not successeded.

```
$row = array(.....);
 $vali = '';
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {

        if( $value[$key] == 'value'){

                echo  $vali .= $value['value'].",";
        }
    }
```

I want to do it in one loop.$row contains multiple arrays like above 3.$row contains all the records that are fetched from data base.hope you understand what $row is.

Comment: What's the actual content of `$row`? One row or multiple rows?

Comment: @Jack $row contains multiple arrays like above 3.

Comment: @Fasilkk Becoz i want to fetch only value field records.

Comment: Then why don't you call it `$rows` instead?

Comment: Your array is multidimensional??

Comment: @Jack perhaps you are right but here i use $row variable for data.

Comment: @Fasilkk check my question i update it.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman then my answer also updated..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) to find out whether the key `'value'` is present in each element of `$row`; you don't need a loop for that at all:

```
foreach ($row as $data) {
    if (isset($data['value'])) {
       $vali .= $data['value'] . ',';
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can build an array with the values:

```
$values = array();
foreach ($row as $data) {
    if (isset($data['value'])) {
        $values[] = $data['value'];
    }
}
echo join(',', $values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your naming suggests that `$row` contains just:

```
Array ( [standards_id] => 1 
    [value] => sory 
    [order] => 10
)
```

There is no reason to loop over such a structure. You can test if this 'row' contains a value with

```
if( isset( $row['value'] ) ) { 
  $vali .= $row['value'] . ', ';
}
```

If you have a variable `$myRows` containing these arrays, you can loop over them using

```
foreach( $myRows as $k => $row ) { ... }
```

In this case `$row` contains the array and you can use the first code to append the value to `$vali`.

Comment: $row store multi arrays at a time.I cannot check only value like you suggest.

Comment: I would suggest to rename that variable then to `$rows` or `$myRows` or something that suggests it holds multiple rows. This helps with the readability of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {

            if( $key == 'value'){

                     $vali .= $value.",";
            }
        }

echo $vali;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$row = array('standards_id' => 1, 'value' => 'saleem', 'order' => 4);
$vali = '';
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    if( $key == 'value'){
        $vali .= $value . ",";
    }
}
echo $vali;
```